# How are 'spam' flags handled?

Tags: discussion, spam

Lately there have been a few "buy coins cheap" kinda posts on Arqade, and it's almost entertaining to see users jump on them and suppress them quickly. Like a bunch of thugs jumping from the shadows to take down a mark, then drag him muffled and struggling back into the darkness...

However it has sparked an interest into how to properly handle them, and how, in turn, the process is handled.

Some posts I have read basically say "Flag. Downvote. Move on." Sure. No probs.

But what should I *actually* do? Flag as spam? Should I VtC as well? What actually happens when I flag as spam?

Comment: Just a note - there is no "u" in Arqade

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag as spam. If enough users flag, the post will be *deleted* (not simply closed), as spam should be. If a moderator notices the flag, he'll generally also burninate the spammy user as well. Sometimes, if the community is too adept, the flag will auto-resolve before a moderator even sees it, in which case the user might survive.

If you really want to make sure a spammer gets annihilated, a 10k user can re-flag the deleted post for moderator attention after it's auto-deleted.

Comment: Given how quickly spam posts are destroyed, mod intervention or otherwise, an unregistered spammy user hanging around isn't the worst thing that could happen.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'd bet that posting spam is a fast way to get yourself question banned (or, rather, severely rate-limited).

Comment: @murgatroid99 While this is true, there are additional filters that kick in at an IP level when an *account* is deleted as a spammer. While we have tools to find accounts with many community-deleted posts, it's quicker/easier if these people come up in our flag queue.